# Is it possibleto implement CI/CD and GIT for Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: devops, microsoft-dynamics, cicd, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to figure out, is there any way to Implement even simple CI/CD pipelines for Dynamics AX 2012 R3. Currently, all the releases are handled as Unmanaged Solutions. All the customisation changes are done in the development environment and each customisation is then added to that unmanaged solution.

Is there any way to export all customizations into git somehow, so people can work on them using Visual Studio and just push changes back?

I know that there is [Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell](https://github.com/seanmcne/Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell), which give us some options, and there are [Power DevOps Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WaelHamze.xrm-ci-framework-build-tasks&ssr=false#overview) but those are mainly for Dynamics 365 as I understand.